# Is call [edi+0x21] valid under the x86-64 instruction set?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, disassembly

Is `call [edi+0x21]` valid under x86-64 instruction set? According to the Intel manual, FF /2 is only valid for r/m64, but an online encoder/decoder that I am testing with outputs `67 ff 57 21`. Is the tool I am using wrong, or is my understanding wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Address size and operand size are independent.  Even if you use a 32 bit address, the memory operand can still have 64 bit size.  So yes, `call [edi+0x21]` is a valid 64 bit mode instruction and the encoding `67 ff 57 21` is correct, too.